# How can I calculate power dissipating through a Eaton moulded circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, power-electronics, power-transmission

Excuse my English. I am trying to figure out how to calculate the power dissipating through a CB by Eaton. Not much info is given on resistance.

Assuming I selected a 250 CB, how can I calculate the power dissipating through it? I tried to estimate the resistance by taking the interupting current 65 kA at 480 V to get a 0.0074 ohm. Say I have 3 phase 480 VAC, 200 amps going through the breaker. Using the P=I<sup>2</sup>R multiplying the 200 by that 0.0074 gives a high value of 296 watts.

I am here because I am not sure if that is the right calculating it. If anyone any suggestions I would appreciate it.

[image]